# Is there a keyboard with both function AND media keys

Tags: keyboards

I just chanced upon a [$200 keyboard](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Logitech-Tenkeyless-LIGHTSPEED-Mechanical-LIGHTSYNC/dp/B07W6JQ1KQ/ref=sr_1_2?keywords=wireless+keyboard&qid=1637870418&refinements=p_36%3A428448031&rnid=428432031&s=computers&sr=1-2) that had both function keys and media keys.

[image]

Modern software IDEs have many, many keyboard shortcuts. They frequently use the function keys. But, on my keyboards I tend to have the keys dedicated to media control - since I value quick action to the volume controls.  This reminded me how clumsy it is to have to use the `fn` key in combination with other modifiers.

Can anybody recommend a modestly priced keyboard which either has both sets of function keys AND media keys, or which at least has function keys plus volume controls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the sharkoon skiller SGK5, which has 5 media keys, a volume wheel and all standard function keys. It also has 5 programmable macro keys, but I don't tend to use those (they are not so easy to program). It has rubberdome switches, is connected over USB and has some basic rgb (perfect for me). In Belgium, it is availible for €42 in AZERTY and QWERTY layouts (a lot cheaper than $200).

Comment: Hi, thanks for that @Irsu85 .  They don't have it where I shop online, but the Logitech G213 keyboard was offered as an alternative - which has media keys.

Comment: You can always look at different webshops